# How to install DB2 ODBC or OLEDB Driver

Tags: odbc, db2, driver, oledb

I have already installed IBM DB2 Database Express on Windows 7 Pro.

Now, I would like to create my C# code in order to select/insert/update records in DB2 tables.

I spend the whole day searching over the internet for links on how to install either OLEDB or ODBC Driver in order to connect to DB2 database. But without success!!!

So, i'm wondering if somebody can help me or send me a useful link to download driver.

Thank you

Comment: you shouldnt have to install any driver explictly to use oledb

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.razorsql.com/docs/help_db2.html

Answer (score 3):

**Download:**

In the webpage: http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/legacy/

With parameters "Information Management" - "IBM Data Server Client Packages" - Custom version and platform

Then write *odbc_cli* in Id Fix

Download the latest fix pack (in my case "IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI (Windows/x86-64 64 bit) V10.5 Fix Pack 7")

**Installation:**

Copy zip into C:\Program Files\IBM (if not exist, you must create the folder)
Extract it

In cmd:

Execute "cd C:\Program Files\IBM\{uncompressed driver folder}\bin" (by default "clidriver")

Execute "db2cli install -setup" for install. If you need uninstall, exec "db2cli install -cleanup"

If you need install it for pointing to 32 bit IBM DB2 ODBC driver for your 32 bit application in a 64-bit environment, read this documentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=71&uid=swg21384435

Note: in version 9.5.* the command changes:
Install: db2oreg1.exe -i
Uninstall: db2oreg1.exe -u

---

In my opinion, I recommend download IBM Client i Access with custom installation, selecting only "ODBC" and "OLE DB Provider"

You can download it by ibm  public ftp: public.dhe.ibm.com (port 21)
in the folder "/as400/products/clientaccess/win32/v7r1m0/servicepack"

Comment: Thank you! I was trying db2oreg1 -setup and it wasn't working at all. db2cli install -setup worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

For DB2 9.7 check here :

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24033685

Download

IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI (64-bit)
(or)
IBM Data Server Runtime Client

HTH

Sathyaram

Comment: This is the easy part. This is a `.zip` that you get. Once downloaded and extracted, how do you register the ODBC driver?

Comment: The IBM site eventually requires an IBM account. What we really need is a link to a `.zip` file

Answer (score 1):

The below link has a detailed walk thru
http://www.ryslander.com/how-to-install-and-configure-db2-odbc-driver/

Answer (score 1):

There is also a microsoft version of the db2 driver (part of host integration server).

In every sql server feature pack you will find a DB2OLEDBV[version]_[architecture].msi

eg. sql2016sp1 has v6 (ENU\DB2OLEDBV6_x64.msi and ENU\DB2OLEDBV6_x86.msi)
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54279

sql2016 rtm has v5
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676

sql2012sp2 has v4
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43339

Infos:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sjackson/2014/06/27/db2-provider-version-information/
- http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241539
- https://www.google.de/search?q=microsoft+sql+feature+pack

a nice overview is available at https://akawn.com/utilities/feature-packs/