# Installing the DB2 9.7 ODBC driver

Tags: db2, odbc

I have downloaded the DB2 ODBC client for Windows on x86, and found out that it's a .zip containing a tree of files. I found no instruction wheresoever on:

- what to do with these files
- how to subsequently register the ODBC driver.

Would anyone know?

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.ryslander.com/how-to-install-and-configure-db2-odbc-driver/

Comment: Too bad. My company's web sas forbids access to this site. I'll have to post a query for access. No wonder why I did not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a common problem, as evidenced at [How to install DB2 ODBC or OLEDB Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074200/how-to-install-db2-odbc-or-oledb-driver) where someone got the ZIP files but had no instructions on how to install them.

http://www.ryslander.com/how-to-install-and-configure-db2-odbc-driver/ has instructions with screenshots on how to install the driver, including registering it.